# Correct location to install Python-docx globally

Tags: python, linux, centos

I am updating this question because the basis of the question was really in error to begin with.

If you're having issues with installing your modules, first check to see if you (like me) followed a tutorial saying to use `sudo -i` to install modules.  This is HORRIBLE advice.  HORRRR IIII  BBBBLE advice.  Your modules will be installed but not really accessible to the users, but then when you try to do things right, and use `sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4` you'll get a message that the module is already installed. So if you know you've installed modules on your server / VPS, Linux, etc. but you can't access them, uninstall them, go to `sudo -i` and uninstall them, make sure that EVERYTHING. IS. CLEAN. of your modules, then go to your admin account and use `sudo pip install <modules name>`.

This will be MUCH better and you won't waste your time trying to figure out what you've done wrong.  Most likely, what you did wrong was follow some stupid tutorial saying to install things as `root@` and it's messed you up from the start.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I believe I was in a virtualenv when I installed it.  If I remember right, it would make sense why it is not available except where I installed it.  I'm still in need of assistance on how to uninstall and fix it where it can be accessed from any account/user given permission to do so.

Comment: What command did you run specifically to install it?

Comment: Can someone explain why the down vote?

Comment: pip3 install python-docx  Then someone else installed MySQLdb for me.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you're asking how to uninstall this package, and then reinstall it globally for the system?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to uninstall it from your version of python 3.4.8, then reinstall it using sudo rights to do it globally.

```
python3 -m pip uninstall python-docx
sudo python3 -m pip install python-docx
```

I'm a little confused though, since in your screenshots, it shows MySQLdb as installed for python2.6, not python3.4. Are you aware of this, and is it part of your problem?

Comment: I have gone into the virtualenv where I knew it was installed, `pip uninstall python-docx`, selected y and uninstalled it.  Confirmed it by trying to uninstall it again and received a message that the package wasn't installed.  I then did `deactivate` to get out the virtualenv, and went to the root director and uninstalled it there for good measure and confirmed.

Any guidance on how to ensure it's installed in the proper directory so it's globally available?

Comment: That depends on how you're installing it. How are you installing it? Is it even installed? The directions you've listed don't include a reinstallation step.

Comment: I want to install it globally so that I can use it on any domain I have.  My apologies if that is not a sufficient answer to your question.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me the reason for the down votes?

Comment: You're asking for how to verify that it was installed to the correct location. But that depends on how you installed it, so I need to know what you did to install the package.

Comment: That was an explanation about what I needed from you to answer your question.

Comment: To address the issue of MySQLdb being installed for 2.6, I'm not sure.  That was done by someone else.  He also upgraded to 3.4.8.  All I know is that MySQLdb works for both users that are on the VPS currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187093/discussion-between-j-allen-morris-and-jordan-singer).